# Merge data by key -- reduce runtime

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two arrays of objects, and I would like to merge some data from one array of objects to the other array by a key. I have a working solution that involves nested `for` loops, but given my data, this takes several seconds. How can I make this faster? I am using D3 v5 in my project.

```js
// Generate data.
let geo = [],
  cases = [];
for (let j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
  geo.push({
    fips: j,
    name: `foobar ${j}`
  })
  cases.push({
    fips: j,
    time: 0,
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
  })
  cases.push({
    fips: j,
    time: 1,
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
  })
  cases.push({
    fips: j,
    time: 2,
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
  })
}
// Order is not guaranteed.
d3.shuffle(geo);
d3.shuffle(cases);

// Print some example data.
console.log(geo[0]);
console.log(cases[0]);


// Merge some data.
for (let gi = 0; gi < geo.length; gi++) {

  for (let ci = 0; ci < cases.length; ci++) {

    if (geo[gi].fips === cases[ci].fips) {
      let thisTime = cases[ci].time;
      geo[gi][thisTime] = {
        "cases": cases[ci].value
      };
      // Cannot break out of loop early because there can be multiple matching 
      // rows in `cases` for each row in `geo`.
    }
  }
}

// Print example of merged data.
console.log("After loops...")
console.log(geo[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the `cases` array into an object indexed by the `fips` property, whose values are the object to merge into the `geo` items, `O(n)`. Then iterate through the `geo` items, and `Object.assign` to them by looking up the `fips` property on the object that was just constructed, also `O(n)`:

```js
// Generate data.
let geo = [],
  cases = [];
for (let j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
  geo.push({
    fips: j,
    name: `foobar ${j}`
  })
  cases.push({
    fips: j,
    time: 0,
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
  })
  cases.push({
    fips: j,
    time: 1,
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
  })
  cases.push({
    fips: j,
    time: 2,
    value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
  })
}
// Order is not guaranteed.
d3.shuffle(geo);
d3.shuffle(cases);

// Merge some data.
const caseValueObjsByFips = {};
for (const aCase of cases) {
  if (!caseValueObjsByFips[aCase.fips]) caseValueObjsByFips[aCase.fips] = {};
  caseValueObjsByFips[aCase.fips][aCase.time] = { cases: aCase.value };
}
for (const item of geo) {
  Object.assign(item, caseValueObjsByFips[item.fips]);
}
// Print example of merged data.
console.log("After loops...")
console.log(geo[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance for teaching me about `Object.assign`. This solution works very well. This is for a visualization of coronavirus cases in the united states (https://kaczmarj.github.io/covid19vis/)